# Moving fields between fieldsets on Dexterity

Tags: plone, archetypes, dexterity

In Archetypes, in order to move a field from a fieldset (or schemata) to another, we can do the following:

```
schema['creators'].schemata = 'default'
```

However, I'm not achieving the same using Dexterity. I've tried using form hints. Ex:

```
form.fieldset('default',
    fields=['creators']
 )
```

I notice that it doesn't work because the field "creators" is unknown at this time. (The ownership behavior wasn't evaluated yet).

Nevertheless, with form hints, I can move from "default" to another (eg. "ownership").

```
myfile = NamedFile(title=_(u"A file"))
form.fieldset('ownership', fields=['myfile'])
```

How can I do that? Writing my own behavior?

Thx!

Comment: Maybe you can manipulate Z3C Form.widgets instance by overriding Form.updateWidgets()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need to make the define the field you want to assign on an interface under your control.  While this seems duplicative, it is a good idea for purposes of being complete and explicit.  You can either:

(1) Declare 'creators' field on your content type interface (likely, recommended solution), or...

(2) Use your own behavior as documented here (and adding this behavior to the type's FTI in portal_types and associated setup XML): http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/behaviors/creating-and-registering-behaviors.html

The first solution should be the easiest.  Any fields that you wish to control fieldset location or order of should likely be defined by your interfaces anyway.

Comment: By following (1), I must do something like `creators = schema.Text()`, at the schema interface, right? I did that, but the `creators` from `IOwnership` didn't overlap the one I declared. Do u have an example?

Comment: Yes, create a 'creators' schema field on your interface, and subclass the IOwnership interface instead of mixing into the FTI as a behavior.  It is likely that the behavior is composed into the plone.autoform groups for the edit form without considering your choice.  If you absolutely must use a behavior, choose route #2 above.