# Moving existing fields/behaviors in dexterity

Tags: plone, dexterity

How can move an existing field (IDublinCore.rights) into another fieldset, after a specific field - Without writing my own Behavior (a copy of IDublinCore)?

"Rights" fields should be appear after "image_caption" (own contenttype)

This isn't working

```
form.order_after(rights='image_caption')
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is by design not possible. two possible workarounds are described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901304/moving-fields-between-fieldsets-on-dexterity

Comment: Thank you, I saw the other question - but i hoped that in the last time, this have changed...

Comment: The answers in the other question are not *quite* directly revelant. There is a much better answer for behavior fields in https://community.plone.org/t/moving-behavior-fields-to-different-fieldset/6219/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using Jquery? (Since the fieldsets are using Jquery anyway)

For example to move Tags under Summary....

```
$('body.template-edit.portaltype-document #formfield-form-widgets-IDublinCore-subjects').insertAfter('#formfield-form-widgets-IDublinCore-description')
```

Note: I only tested this in Firebug's Script window...

Comment: Not that perfect solution, but a good (simple) one - thank you