# How I order behavior IDublinCore in Dexterity Type?

Tags: python, plone, zope, dexterity, plone-4.x

I'm writing a product using Python Dexterity Type, and I have `Title` and `Description`, this fields come from a behavior `plone.app.dexterity.behaviors.metadata.IDublinCore`, but I neeed reorder this fields with my fields.

Example:

My fields: document, collage, age, biography

IDublinCore: Title, Description

The order: collage, Title, document, age, biography, Description

How I Do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you got your own Dexterity Type you can handle with `form directives` aka `setting taggedValues` on the interface.

```
from plone.autoform import directives


class IYourSchema(model.Schema):

    directives.order_before(collage='IDublinCore.title')
    collage = schema.TextLine(
        title=u'Collage',
    )
```

You find excellent documentation about this feature in the plone documentation  http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/reference/form-schema-hints.html#appearance-related-directives

Comment: Worked like a glove, simple and Pythonic, Thx!

Answer (score 0):

How about using Jquery? (Since the fieldsets are using Jquery anyway)

For example to move Tags under Summary....

```
$('body.template-edit.portaltype-document #formfield-form-widgets-IDublinCore-subjects').insertAfter('#formfield-form-widgets-IDublinCore-description')
```

Note: This is a copy of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31205979/3046069)

Comment: where I put this code? I'm novice and this is my second product.

Comment: That's a separate qu... but start here http://docs.plone.org/4/en/develop/addons/javascript.html then ask on #plone IRC for help